# '/bin/convert_to_uff.py': No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, tensorrt, nvidia-docker

I am trying to optimize `YoloV3` using `tensorRT`

I came this post called [Have you Optimized your Deep Learning Model Before Deployment?](https://towardsdatascience.com/have-you-optimized-your-deep-learning-model-before-deployment-cdc3aa7f413d)

`Docker` is used in the post.

Used [Enabling GPUs in the Container Runtime Ecosystem](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/gpu-containers-runtime/) to install `nvidia-docker2`

Pulled the latest version of the docker image `docker pull aminehy/tensorrt-opencv-python3:version-1.3` from [aminehy/tensorrt-opencv-python3](https://hub.docker.com/r/aminehy/tensorrt-opencv-python3/tags)

Here are the images

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                        TAG                             IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nvcr.io/nvidia/cuda               10.1-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04   b4879c167fc1        2 weeks ago         3.67GB
aminehy/tensorrt-opencv-python3   version-1.3                     0302e477816d        4 months ago        5.36GB
aminehy/tensorrt-opencv-python3   latest                          604502819d12        4 months ago        4.94GB
aminehy/tensorrt-opencv-python3   version-1.1                     d693210c500c        4 months ago        4.94GB
```

I ran

````
$sudo docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/workspace --runtime=nvidia -w /workspace -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY aminehy/tensorrt-opencv-python3:version-1.3```

=====================
== NVIDIA TensorRT ==
=====================

NVIDIA Release 19.05 (build 6392482)

NVIDIA TensorRT 5.1.5 (c) 2016-2019, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.
Container image (c) 2019, NVIDIA CORPORATION.  All rights reserved.

https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt

To install Python sample dependencies, run /opt/tensorrt/python/python_setup.sh

root@a38b20eeb740:/workspace# cd /opt/tensorrt/python/
root@a38b20eeb740:/opt/tensorrt/python# chmod +x python_setup.sh 
root@a38b20eeb740:/opt/tensorrt/python# ./python_setup.sh
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from -r /opt/tensorrt/samples/sampleSSD/requirements.txt (line 1)) (6.0.0)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Ignoring torch: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
......
......
......
Setting up graphsurgeon-tf (5.1.5-1+cuda10.1) ...
Setting up uff-converter-tf (5.1.5-1+cuda10.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from uff import converters, model  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/model/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import uff_pb2 as uff_pb  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uff/model/uff_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.internal import enum_type_wrapper
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf.internal
chmod: cannot access '/bin/convert_to_uff.py': No such file or directory
````

Can't seem to find any file called `convert_to_uff.py` inside `bin`

Whats is going?

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: That's certainly not part of any standard install. Maybe you skipped over something earlier in the instructions?

Comment: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025246/jetson-tx2/where-is-convert-to-uff suggests that this is available from a Python package called `uff` (and probably that you did not google before asking).

Comment: @tripleee I am using `GTX` not `Jetson` Platfrom. Should have still worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling protobuf to be sure:

```
pip install protobuf
```

Comment: Close enough since this error is for `python2` `python -m pip install protobuf` worked